# Several Issues WOWZA server setup

Tags: wowza

I need to duplicate a WOWZA server on Azure can rtsp a file with send report in RTCP.
All I need is to do rtsp://wowzaserver:1935/vod/sample.mp4 with sender report.
We have an existing WOWZA Server 4.7.7 on Ubuntu can do so.
I setup on on Azure Windows Server 2012 with WOWZA 4.8.5
ffplay rtsp://wowzaserver:1935/vod/sample.mp4 work
But I see UDP timeout use TCP and I don't see sender report in WireShark

I tried to compare the Server.xml and Application.xml of both server and cannot fix it.
Not sure it is configure issue or Azure Firewall issue.

[image]

Left is Azure one, Right is Local one with RTCP sender report.

[image]

And I don't understand, why my WOWZA missing Setup, Properties and Module tab.  Is that critical?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the actual issue, but if I'd have to bet, I'd say firewall, since you checked the rest of the config.

However, the missing tabs are certainly because you didn't check this box in your user's configuration:
[image]